# Laravel base64_decode error on fresh install

Tags: php, laravel, installation, base64, mcrypt

I'm trying to get started with laravel but it seems like hell to get it working.

First of all, here is the error (this happens when i try to access */myapp/public*):

[image: Laravel base64_decode error]

Some considerations:

1. I'm using MAMP Pro with php 5.4.4
2. Already installed MCrypt extension
3. Already gave app/storage write permission
4. Already optimized artisan by running `php artisan optimize`

Don't know where to go from here, can you help?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I'm using OSX and php5 json is already enabled

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that you gave an array, not a string.

Basically its saying $paylod = array('something'=>'somethingelse');

So it is expecting you provide it with $payload['something'] so that it knows what string to decode.

have you installed/enabled php5 JSON support?

When I set up laravel on a fresh ubuntu 13.10 server I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

among other needed modules (like mcrypt) for laravel 4 to work.